# C#: String[] of lines, use 2D char array with ToCharArray() to store each line?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, parsing, char

I am struggling to figure out how to parse out a String array[] that stores the lines of a file.
I want to store each line in a spot of the 2d char array... I was hoping it would look something like this:
char chararray[,] = {(l,i,n,e,1), (l,i,n,e,2), (l,i,n,e,3), ...};
And so on.

I have a for loop that I'm using to try and parse into each spot, or even just parse out into a large char array.

```
for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++)   // increment through the contents of each line in this for statement
    {
        int count = 0;
        chararrayoftags[count] = linesArray[j].ToCharArray();
        //array2Db = linesArray[j].ToCharArray();

        count++;

    }
```

My purpose is to be able to reference line 1 and read it's contents separately... along with all the other lines.

Please be kind to me, I'm taking a leap of faith using StackOverflow, I've only had negative experiences on this site and hope this can be a positive learning experience for me, so that I can figure out how to do this. I just want to learn how to do it.

Comment: What's the point of using a 2D `char` array? If you already have a `string[]` array of the lines, just access each line through the `string[]` array directly, and act on the `string` as needed. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I suppose that is something I could do, my purpose is essentially to parse out "tags" from a mathml file. I need to read the "<" character, then move on to the next characters which would be something like "apply" within the brackets. I wanted the characters separated so I can do that more easily, so if I wanted to store the contents inside the brackets somewhere separate I can.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mathml, but it just looks like an xml file structure. Look into xml parsing libraries because if you try to do this yourself you will be in for a world of pain once you need to work with anything that isn't absolutely trivial. In short: *Don't do this sort of work yourself. There are libraries to accomplish what you need.*

Comment: I know right!!!!! But it's a work assignment and I'm just doing what I'm told. :'(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sorry you've had bad experiences in the past. Hopefully we can help change that. What... were you told, exactly? Did someone say, "I need this method to return a 2-dimensional array with the contents of the file in it?" Or was it more like, "I need you to write something that finds the names of all the tags in the MathML file?"

Comment: I was told to write code that can parse mathml files, that contain basic equations (pemdas equations) written in mathml. 
I was told to simply parse out a file of (for example addition between like x+y) integers. I don’t have to compute anything, I just need it to parse the file correctly, read the tags (so it knows what the operation its because mathml tags all have the meaning) place it on a stack or something. I am really stresses about it actually because I don’t know how to do this and there doesn’t seem to be much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were really looking for something like a 2d character array, `File.ReadAllLines()` returns a `string[]`, and each `string` acts, for most purposes, like a `char[]`. So I wouldn't bother trying to create a 2D array. For a true 2D array, you'd need to have a fixed width in your document, which doesn't make much sense in this case. You're probably asking for a *jagged array*, which you can get like this:

```
char[][] arr = File.ReadAllLines("filename").Select(l => l.ToCharArray()).ToArray();
```

But if you're really trying to parse out MathML, I'd suggest using an xml-parsing library. XDocument and its related classes are likely to be much easier to reason with:

```
foreach(var applyElement in XDocument.Load("filename").Descendants("apply"))
{

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You wouldn't believe how much the first part has helped me! I find the jagged array concept to be really really interesting... how does it know how much memory to allocate for the array?

Comment: Due to how C#'s memory model works, arrays sit in the heap, and variables that reference them are just pointers. That means each entry in the outer array is just a pointer to another array on the heap somewhere, so the system only needs to know how many "lines" there will be, to determine how much space to allocate for that array: the size of the inner arrays don't impact the space allocated for the outer one.

Comment: In terms of how a method like `ToArray()` or `ReadAllLines()` figures out how big an array to create, it's similar to how any arraylist implementation (like C#'s List) works: it starts by populating a small array and every time it runs out of space it allocates a larger array (usually doubling the size) and copies the entries into the front of that array. Once it finishes reading, it can see how much space it actually needed, and copy all the values into a brand-new array of exactly that size. Sometimes `ToArray()` can guess the correct size up front if the input argument knows how big it is.